# WebDeploy and SetACL - too slow in case of lots of files/folders

Tags: asp.net, acl, web-deployment, one-click-web-publishing

We have an ASP.Net MVC3 site which we're publishing on IIS using web deploy.

Under the site root we have a `"Data"` folder which we're using to store uploaded files and the result of their processing. 
So, there are lots of files/folders under `"Site Root/Data"` at the moment.

Web deploy is trying to change ACL permissions when publishing and it takes more than 10 minutes in our case (lots of files/folders).

Now we're using

```
<includesetaclproviderondestination>False</includesetaclproviderondestination>
```

to completely disable setacl provider, but sometimes it's handy to be able to change permissions on newly added dirs with web deploy.

So, the question is - what could we do in this case besides turning aclprovider off?
Is there a way to set acl permissions non-recursively with web-deploy to make it faster?